# Use ogrinfo to get names from column and count rows of large(ish) geopackage

Tags: gdal, ogr, geopackage

I think this is a really silly question, yet I can't solve it quickly now:

I want to work with this rather large geopackage: https://data.statistik.gv.at/data/OGDEXT_RASTER_1_STATISTIK_AUSTRIA_LAEA_GPKG.zip

Besides not being really sure how to handle such a big geopackage, I (for now) just want to know the columnames. And the columnnames I just want to know to count the rows using this `ogrinfo` call:

```
ogrinfo -dialect sqlite -sql "select count(cellcode) as num_cellcode" STATISTIK_AUSTRIA_RASTER_LAEA_3035.gpkg
```

However, it throws me the error:

```
INFO: Open of `STATISTIK_AUSTRIA_RASTER_LAEA_3035.gpkg'
      using driver `GPKG' successful.
ERROR 1: In ExecuteSQL(): sqlite3_prepare_v2(select count(code_sdmx) as num_cellcode):
  no such column: code_sdmx
```

I used the name `cellcode` as the command: `ogrinfo -al STATISTIK_AUSTRIA_RASTER_LAEA_3035.gpkg` lists the following:

```
OGRFeature(l000100):12943
  cellcode (String) = 100mN27263E47266
  code_sdmx (String) = AT_CRS3035RES100mN2726300E4726600
  code_su (String) = CRS3035RES100mN2726300E4726600
  POLYGON ((4726600 2726300,4726600 2726400,4726700 2726400,4726700 2726300,4726600 2726300))
```

So my question would be how to get the littel sql-query to run and count the number of rows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This GeoPackage contains multiple layers. If you want the count from the `l000100` layer, this would be your command:

```
ogrinfo -dialect sqlite -sql "select count(cellcode) as num_cellcode from l000100" STATISTIK_AUSTRIA_RASTER_LAEA_3035.gpkg
```

Comment: thanks!! I missed that there are multiple layers...